# Можно ли использовать класс string вместе со scanf?

Tags: c++, c

Для вывода объекта класса `string` с помощью `printf` можно воспользоваться методом `c_str()`

```
std::string str = "ala";
printf("%s", str.c_str());
```

Но этот метод, конечно, нельзя использовать для записи строки с помощью `scanf`. Есть ли какие-то возможности для записи в `string` напрямую, без использования дополнительного массива `char`?

Comment: Это означает установить закрытые данные  класса извне. Напрямую  нет

Comment: А использовать стандартные с++ функции запрещает преподаватель или старый тимлид? Использование scanf + std::string вместе - моветон.

Comment: @KoVadim о, еще один) Ну окей, раскажи ты мне тогда, как использовать стандартные средства С++ в окне curses. Я с радостью послушаю)

Comment: Я думаю, что Ваш комментарий немного грубоватый. Плюс, в вопросе нигде не написано, curses. В результате мы решаем проблему XY/молотка. Но в любом случае, можно написать обёртку. А грубить всегда успеете.

Comment: @KoVadim а разве это: А использовать стандартные с++ функции запрещает преподаватель или старый тимлид? - не было грубо? По мне так довольно грубо! И то что не указан `curses` нигде в вопросе - а зачем, скажите мне? В вопросе разве где-то фигурирует `curses`? Нет, вопрос конкретно про `scanf`, а не про `scanw` - аналог `scanf` для `curses`. Так почему я должен указывать `curses`? Для таких умников, как Вы, которым охота других поучать? Уж извините, но если вы будете кому-то грубить, то не удивляйтесь, когда получите грубость в ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя придумать всегда возможно:

```
string s;
s.reserve(100);
scanf("%99s",  const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()));
s = string(s.c_str());
cout << s;
```

Comment: комментируйте в чем проблема

Comment: я думал о чем-то похожем, но я не уверен в сохранности данных: s.c_str() - он вернет указатель с выделенной под него памятью в 100 байт? Да и возвращаемое значение - оно точно будет одинаково? Да и приведение типа с const_cast - как-то не оч. Кстати, у меня не ругался компилятор, когда я не приводил тип.

Comment: Не будет проблем никаких, поскольку не нарушена никакая логика. Присваивание восстанавливает инвариант

Comment: хм, тогда решение можно признать рабочим, но все-таки, оно не далеко ушло от объявление дополнительного массива `char`. Думаю, все-таки, так будет даже понятнее. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Да, не используется дополнительный массив, зато используется  временный строковой обьект,

Comment: Очень сомнительное решение. `reserve` выделяет память, но не гарантирует ее сохранения! Пока `string` не будет корректно инициализирован - все, что за пределами `length()` байт может быть в любой момент переписано, например! Да и на кой использовать `c_str()`, если `data()` в С++17 возвращает именно *изменяемый* массив? И еще сущает `s = string(s.c_str());` - формально вы создаете новую строку, нет? Тогда какой глубокий смысл в отказе от буфера? *Создавайте*, как я предложил, строку, потом пишите в `data()`, ну и вызываете `resize()`. Нет лишних телодвижений и памяти; все в рамках стандарта :)

Comment: https://ideone.com/ioUGIa

Comment: а если компилятор не поддерживает С++17?.. И что значит  reserve не гарантирует сохранения памяти?  Я не согласен

Comment: Он не гарантирует, что *неиспользуемая часть памяти* не будет ничем заполнена - скажем, для каких-то внутренних рабочих нужд. Т.е *теоретически* вы можете записать туда что-то, а после этого обнаружить, что записано уже что-то совсем не то. И это никак не будет нарушать контракт `string`. Если компилятор не поддерживает C++17 - или не лезть сюда вовсе (что правильно!), или использовать хотя бы `data()` - поскольку `c_str()` добавляет завершающий нуль, *теоретически* может оказаться, что это просто временно созданная строка.

Answer (score 2):

Формально [начиная с C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), `string::data()` возвращает `char*`, т.е. вроде бы можно... Но только все равно потом надо напильником... - чтоб, например, правильно длина возвращалась.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s(10,' ');
    strcpy((char*)s.data(),"Hello");
    s.resize(5);
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << s.length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/ioUGIa

Comment: окей, если я, например, выделил память в `str.resize(10)`, а потом вызываю `scanf("%9s", str.data());` то что произойдет? Метод вернет указатель на `char` с выделенной памятью на 10 элементов и, после записи, этот массив символов запишется в str?

Comment: Вроде как да. Только последний 0 тоже будет входить в `string` - у него нет ограничений на то, что входит в строку. Кстати, вот примерчик: https://ideone.com/uI0hyM - правда, тут пришлось приводить тип, но в C++17, например, VC++2017 - работает и без этого.