# C++. Вылетает на повторном вызове delete[]

Tags: c++, указатели

Функция подгружает данные с файла. Перед каждой новой загрузкой пытаюсь почистить данные в массиве, чтобы подгрузить все заново. При этом на второй раз вылетает в точке `delete[]`.

[image: Вот эта самая ошибка]

Вот и сама функция:

```
void uploadData(Person *& persons, int & size, std::string path) {

    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open(path, std::fstream::in);
    if (!fs.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error with opening file. Try again\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if (persons != nullptr) {
            delete[] persons;
        }

        MetaData metaData;
        fs.read((char*)&metaData, sizeof(MetaData));
        size = metaData.getSize();
        persons = new Person[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            fs.read((char*)&persons[i], sizeof(Person));
        }
        std::cout << "Data was successfully uploaded\n";
    }
    fs.close();
}
```

А вот такая функция работает без проблем:

```
void check(Person *& persons) {
    if (persons != nullptr) {
        delete[] persons;
    }
    persons = new Person[2];
    persons[0].setInfo();
}
```

Помогите добрые люди разобраться с ситуацией. А то что-то туплю уж не первый час
Код из `main()`, на котором крашится

```
int main() {
    std::string path = "Storage.txt";
    Person * a = nullptr;
    int size = 0;

    std::string todo;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << ">>";
        std::cin >> todo;
        if (todo == "pushPerson") pushPerson(a, size);
        if (todo == "showAll") showAll(a, size);
        if (todo == "uploadData") uploadData(a, size, path);
        if (todo == "saveData") saveData(a, size, path);

    }

    system("pause");
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Класс Person вот:

```
class Person
{
public:
    std::string getName();
    int getAge();
    int getSalary();

    void setName(std::string name);
    void setAge(int age);
    void setSalary(int salary);

    void setInfo();
    void showInfo();
private:
    int salary;
    int age;
    std::string name;
}
```

Comment: добавьте код из main() или код, использующий функции

Comment: Добавьте определения класса `Person`, да и `MetaData`. Есть у меня большое подозрение, что это не POD, а вы его просто `read`'ом читаете... Вот **редко** такое `fs.read((char*)&persons[i], sizeof(Person));` бывает без проблем...

Comment: @BlackDesk Еще раз настоятельно прошу привести определение класса `Person`.

Comment: К слову, в блоке `if (persons != nullptr) {delete[] persons; }` проверка указателя избыточна. `delete` уже проверяет его на `NULL` перед освобождением памяти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот это:

```
std::string name;
```

в составе класса `Person` делает недопустимым запись и чтение с помощью функций `write` и `read` из памяти. Потому что в `name` содержится, например, не сама строка, а указатель на нее. При записи вы сохраняете в файле какой-то адрес, потом считываете его - когда он уже давно не актуален, а при удалении вызов деструктора пытается удалить память по несуществующему адресу...

Такие классы нужно записывать и читать иначе - например, в вашем случае для `int`-поля можно писать и так, но вот `name` я бы писал так - сначала размер строки, потом содержимое. При чтении - читал размер, выделял буфер, в него читал строку, а потом уже инициализировал ею поле `name`.

Ну, или, если у вас C++17 - без промежуточного буфера, как описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821385/195342).

Answer (score 0):

С использованием The C++ Programming Language Special Edition 2015 Страуструпа (пункт 15.6.1 Выделение памяти под массивы):

```
#include <iostream>


//класс содержит только число
class Test
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    explicit Test(int a):data(a)
    {
    }
    Test():data(0){}
    void set(int a)
    {
        data = a;
    }
    void show()
    {
        std::cout<<data<<std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Test(){}




};



void update(Test* array, int size, int times=1)
{
    if(array != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] array;
    }

    array = new Test[size];

    array[0].set(100*times); //обновление данных
    array[1].set(200*times);

}
int main() {

    auto p = new Test[2];
    p[0].set(1);
    p[1].set(2);


    update(p, 2); // в первый раз умножаются данные на дефолт-значение, на 1
    p[0].show();
    update(p, 2, 2); // теперь на 2
    p[0].show();
    //Доказательство, что данные обновлены

    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь представлен примитивно принцип работы Вашей программы. В книге в указанном пункте показывается такой пример инициализации массива:

```
    void f(int s)
{
    Employee* p = new Employee[s];
    //... 
    delete[] p;
}
```

У Вас же массив инициализируется нулевым указателем:

```
Person * a = nullptr;
```

(Так же не забывайте про виртуальный деструктор, если Вы будете наследовать от этого класса)